# Is this a correct way to add/remove views?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

Lets say that I have 4 view controllers (call them FirstView,SecondView,ThirdView,FourthView) which are created programmatically and all are in separate files:

In AppDelegate.m didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method I have these lines of code

```
self.rootViewController = [[rootViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"rootViewController" bundle:nil];
self.window.rootViewController = self.rootViewController;
```

In rootViewController.m loadview method I have

```
self.view = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].applicationFrame];
self.firstView = [[FirstView alloc]init];
[self.view addSubview:self.firstView.view];
```

That code works fine - first view is displayed.

Let's continue

In FirstView.m  switchViews method

NOTE: Please see the comments in code

```
 self.secondView = [[SecondView alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondView" bundle:nil];


// I think here secondView is added to rootViewController - right ?
[self.view.superview addSubview:self.secondView.view];

// Here first view is removed from rootViewController - right ?
[self.view removeFromSuperview];
```

Here is how I add/remove views.

Is this approach correct?
Can you recommend a better solution?

I have read about UINavigationController, but I don't think it could be a solution in this case.

Comment: `self.view = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].applicationFrame];
self.firstView = [[FirstView alloc]init];
[self.view addSubview:self.firstView.view];` This is incorrect. Apple explicitly doesn't agree with this technique.

Comment: I think better way will be if your `rootViewController` will manage view switching using delegate, notificaition or any other pattern.

Comment: @danipralea you mean that apple will reject the app ?

Comment: I don't know. Check the app review guidelines. But I surely do remember that I've read this in their documentation. Either it's discouraged, or rejected. Something around that...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You say:

> I have 4 views (call them FirstView ...

Then you say:

```
[self.view addSubview:self.firstView.view];
```

Which makes me think that `FirstView` isn't actually a `UIView` - as you claim it is. Instead, it's probably a `UIViewController` - a different beast altogether.

If my suspicion is correct - then you are "off-track" so to speak.

Going beyond that to your sample code snippet:

```
self.secondView = [[SecondView alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondView" bundle:nil];

// I think here secondView is added to rootViewController - right ?
[self.view.superview addSubview:self.secondView.view];

// Here first view is removed from rootViewController - right ?
[self.view removeFromSuperview];
```

This is definitely not a great idea. Here's why:

**First:** your view controller doesn't explicitly "know" anything about the superview you are so casually inserting and removing subviews to/from - so it shouldn't do that. You may, alternatively, create your own view and insert/remove subviews from that - which would not only be perfectly acceptable but also common practice.

**Second:** if these are actually `UIViewController`s like I think they are - then you are not properly handling hooking them up to the `UIViewController` event chain - which means methods on these subclasses like `viewDidAppear:` or `viewDidUnload` will not fire.

Comment: @objlv - I thought so. My post is still a valid commentary on what you're doing though. You're breaking the `UIViewController` hierarchy by doing what you're doing - and your `UIViewController`s won't function as expected. It will cause you a world of hurt.

Answer (score 0):

From what I see in your code, `UINavigationController` seems like it would help. If you don't want a navigation bar, you can definitely hide it, but the methods in `UINavigationController` should help you with switching views.

If your views only need to display temporarily, you could also use Modal View controllers. An example of Modal View controllers can be found [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ModalViewControllers/ModalViewControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH111-SW15).

**If you haven't already, check out the [View Controller Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ModalViewControllers/ModalViewControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH111-SW1) from Apple.**